# do I store long strings in tables or in a separate text file?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where fields are 40 varchars long, but from time to time I would have to store text ( 250-1000 characters long ) there. What would be the best solution, to try and fit it into the table or just make a separate text file associated with each table?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438471/is-it-good-to-store-long-strings-in-a-database

Comment: I don't understand... it is the same field that usually is 40 char long that sometimes becomes 250-1000 char long? If it's not exactly the same thing you should use 2 different columns of your table.

Maybe clarify the specifics of your problem.

Comment: >>> Maybe clarify the specifics of your problem.
Let's suppose I have to columns, one EVEN, other DATA. For example, if EVEN is 'got a car, license plate' then DATA is 'ABC-123'. Or if EVEN is 'got married, wife's name' then DATA is 'Jane'. But if EVEN is 'got a 10 page letter', then DATA would he to contain a rather long string of text. So the question is, is it worth it to store seldom large amounts of text in a database or it is better to store them in a separate text file and just a link to it in the DB.

Comment: I'd advise against abbreviating column names.  The clarity of having 'Event' as the column name instead of 'EVEN' is worth way more than the extra byte or two for the schema to store the 't'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to keep everything in the database, then you don't have to jump through loops when accessing the database remotely ( or when doing backups )

Comment: but is it reasonable to make a DATA field, say, 1000+ characters long, if 95% of the time it won't contain more then 40 characters?

Comment: @ user296516: a varchar(2048) field takes no more (read: very little, if any, so ignore delta ) space than a varchar(40) field when you store 40char into it. Anders is correct +1 from me!

Comment: yes, you're right! I changed varchar from 40 to 500 and the DB size didn't even change! :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `text` type instead of `varchar` there.